# Strange behaviour in dask apply with loop of lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda, scope, dask

I am not sure if this is a bug of dask or a feature of python. Simple example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'tags': [['dog'], ['cat', 'red'], ['cat'], ['cat', 'red'], ['cat', 'red'], ['dog', 'red']]})
print data

          tags
0       [dog]
1  [cat, red]
2       [cat]
3  [cat, red]
4  [cat, red]
5  [dog, red]
```

I want to create "hot-columns" for each tag

```
tags = ['cat', 'dog', 'red']
```

using dask:

```
data = dd.from_pandas(data, npartitions=4)

for tag in tags:
    data[tag] = data.tags.apply(lambda x: tag in x, meta=(tag, bool))
```

the result is wrong:

```
print data.compute()
         tags    cat    dog    red
0       [dog]  False  False  False
1  [cat, red]   True   True   True
2       [cat]  False  False  False
3  [cat, red]   True   True   True
4  [cat, red]   True   True   True
5  [dog, red]   True   True   True
```

is seems that the `lambda` is always bounded to the last tag in the loop (`red`). If I unroll the loop manually it works correctly.

Using plain pandas I don't have this problem.

## Partial solution

```
def is_in(items, value):
    return value in items

for tag in tags:
    data[tag] = data.tags.apply(is_in, value=tag, meta=(tag, bool))
```

I don't like it very much since it force the order of the argument to be quite unnatural. By the way I am not sure to have understood the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here: [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture/2295372#2295372) and it is about the lexical scoping of python.

Better solution: use default values with lambda

```
for tag in tags:
    data[tag] = data.tags.apply(lambda x, t=tag: t in x, meta=(tag, bool))
```